# How can I create a custom field in confluence

Tags: confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

How can I create a custom field in confluence that should appear on page edit?
Basically a search bar field where I can search a user and pick them to take some action.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such concept of custom field in Confluence. But, if I understand your requirement correctly then you are looking for **[Task List](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/add-assign-and-view-tasks-590260030.html)**. You can search for a username, pick the one you need and assign to a task.
[image]

Let me know if you are looking for something else or this answer helped you to solve your problem.

***EDIT***

After understanding the problem in detail I have updated the answer as below:
You can develop a macro which takes username as an input and store the required information and send edit notification to the user under cc. You will need to explore dipper inside the APIs in order to implement custom email notification.

Comment: Thanks MrKumar. I am trying to implement a CC field in confluence similar to watchers so that I can send diff of the changes on a page edit to the person mentioned in CC field.

Comment: Also this CC field should appear to every confluence page on page edit irrespective of Space.

Comment: You can develop a macro which takes username as an input and store the required information and send edit notification to the user under cc. You will need to explore dipper inside the APIs  in order to implement custom email notification. 
Does not page properties serve the purpose of adding stakeholders and Confluence email updates?